# Magento 2 : How to remove the default Store langauge code from the URL

Tags: magento2, adminhtml, url, admin-panel

I have integrated multi language stores one for "EN" and second for "DE"
After changed options "Add Store Codes to URL"=>"YES"

(Magento2:: System -> Configuration -> Web -> Add Store Codes to URL=>YES)

German - http://www.domain.com/de/product-url

English - http://www.domain.com/en/product-url

But now I want to remove "/en" only from English URL.
so my both URLs would be like below.

German - http://www.domain.com/de/product-url

English - http://www.domain.com/product-url

Also i have checked many answers but not related Magento-2

Please any suggestions for Magento2 ?